# Character encoding at stream level

Tags: c++, string, unicode, encoding, stream

Reading a lot about encoding finally I got confused!
I summarize my confusion into two questions:

1. is there any `encoding` at `stream` level? I mean, is setting the `encoding` of an `stream` has any meaning? or streams are totally unaware of encoding?
2. If `streams` are unaware of `encoding`, then what's the main purpose of `std::locale` and `std::imbue`?

Comment: For working with wide characters, see the bottom half of http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/

Answer (score 1):

1. No, not really. Although all file I/O operations performed through `std::basic_filebuf<CharT>` use the `std::codecvt<CharT, char, std::mbstate_t>` facet of the locale imbued in the stream.
2. The main purpose of `std::basic_ios::imbue` is to make the stream to format stuff in a locale dependent manner. For instance the decimal separator, thousand separator, and such.

Comment: what's the default `std::codecvt` then?

Comment: @MBZ: The `std::codecvt<char, char, std::mbstate_t>` does nothing, the `std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>` does locale- and compiler-specific conversion between wide string and narrow string. See your compiler documentation for information about the `wchar_t` one.